# How do i add whatsapp api link to email orders using the customer phone number?

Tags: api, email, woocommerce, whatsapp

I would like to add whatsapp link to admin complete orders email, that takes the customer phone number, and adds it to the whatsapp api link.

The idea is that, when i receive notification about order, i can contact my customer using whatsapp and let him know i got his order.

so it should look like this:
api.whatsapp.com/send?phone= {{customer phone number}} &text=...

[image: example for email + location of link]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php and changes the text messages as per you.

```
function add_wp_link_woocommerce_completed_order_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ||  $email->id == 'new_order' ) {
        $link = 'https://wa.me/'.$order->get_billing_phone( 'edit' ).'/?text='.urlencode( 'your text messages' );
        echo '<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
        <h2>'.__( 'Customer WhatsApp link', 'text-domain' ) .'</h2>
        <p><a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.__( 'Contact', 'text-domain' ).'</a></p>
    </div>';
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'add_wp_link_woocommerce_completed_order_email', 99, 4 );
```

Comment: The other solution would be to modify the template. For this he / you need to copy it to your child theme. Both solutions can work. You need to chose one.

Comment: Can you add snippet for the template? the correct template is "admin-new-order.php"
ive tried the snippet above and it didnt work. i changed it to:

...    if ( $email->id == 'admin-new-order' ) { ...
but the email won't change.